# Is there a comma after 'I' in "You can trust that I, and my team of professionals..."

Tags: commas

> You can trust that I, and my team of professionals are your best option for health insurance coverage.

Is the comma optional? Because I would like to go without it because though I like this phrasing it is a bit clunky as it is.

Comment: You don't need the comma, but perhaps it might be a little more colloquial, or more euphonious, to change the order to "You can trust that my team of professional and I..." The words "I and" don't sound good together.

Comment: If you use a comma after "I" then you should put one after "professionals".

Comment: It depends on how that sentence ends …

Comment: "You can trust that I, and my team of professionals are your best option for health insurance coverage." @JasonBassford

Comment: @Renoldus Yes, almost nobody would find that acceptable. Either remove the comma, or, as in a previous comment, add a comma after *professionals*.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I'd think "me, and my" is better... You?

Comment: @Malady Although that certainly *sounds* better than "I and", it isn't grammatically correct. We don't say, "Me is (your best option)", but "I am (your best option)". "I" is the subject, not the object. We would say, "You can trust me and my team", but not "You can trust *that* me and my team *are*...

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - "I and" just sounds *wrong*...

Answer (score -1):

This is called the Oxford Comma

> The Oxford (or serial) comma is the final comma in a list of things...
> Use of the Oxford comma is stylistic, meaning that some style guides
> demand its use while others don’t.
> https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

In your example there are only two items in the list but it still counts as a list.